# parse json and get values with same type

Tags: json, shell, parsing, jq

In the below json, I'm unable to get the value which have reporter only.
the output should be jhoncena only which should written into a file.

```
jq -r '.values' response.json | grep reporter
```

the output for this is

```
"name": "reporter-jhoncena"
```

```json
{
  "size": 3,
  "limit": 25,
  "isLastPage": true,
  "values": [
    {
      "name": "hello-world"
    },
    {
      "name": "test-frame"
    },
    {
      "name": "reporter-jhoncena"
    }
  ],
  "start": 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `capture` :

```
jq -r '.values[].name
  | capture("^reporter-(?<name>.*)").name
  ' response.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` such as

```
jq -r '.values[2].name | split("-")[1]' response.json
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Lx2zl6BL66)</kbd>

**Edit** : Alternatively you can use

```
jq -r '.values[].name | select(.|split("-")[0]=="reporter")|split("-")[1]' response.json > outfile.txt
```

without knowing the order of the name element within the array

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Nr77-Gw_tF)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, this works for value when is fixed. Just not sure how to get with a random value. e.g values[10] and random values for different json. Also, the second answer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yes you're right @steve I've just edited.

Comment: thanks @barbaros. but it still is not working unfortunately.

Comment: you're welcome @steve , what do you get as error

Comment: there's no error. I'm trying on mac. however, exit code is 0.

Comment: These will fail if the name contains `-` (i.e. if `.name` contains two `-`), which doesn't seem that unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '.values[]
  | select(.name|index("reporter"))
  | .name
  | sub("reporter-";"")' in.json > out.txt
```

Of course you might wish to use a different selection criterion, e.g. using  `startswith` or `test`.

Comment: `startswith(str)` and `ltrimstr(str)` can be used as well: `jq -r '.values[] | .name | select(startswith("reporter-")) | ltrimstr("reporter-")'`

Comment: I don't like the fact that this looks for "reporter" anywhere in the name